# Is there any repeater with power amplifier?

Tags: sensor, amplifier, signal, distance

I installed sensor module connected with controller. Those are connected with 6-wire cable, and it consists of 2-wire power(5V & GND), 4-wire signals(0~5V analog). First time, I thought distance will be at most 15m. But the distance can be decided depends on the field. Sometimes it can be over 60m, long!

I tested with 40m cable I have. I saw voltage drop in power line about 0.4 ~ 0.5V, and it makes trouble with proper operation. I wonder if any related device for power amplifier with repeater for amplifying receiving signal like this case.

I searched some device store, but couldn't find proper options. If I cannot do that, gonna modify the design.

Jiwon

Comment: Whats the circuitry like for the analog sensors? Sounds like you might want a powered unity gain buffer down at the sensor's end

Comment: In this scenario not only do you have the problem of the power supply drooping, but also the accuracy of your measurements is likely to be affected, especially if you are referencing them to the "power" ground. I'd look at transmitting the measurements as data over RS485 or similar for that sort of distance, moving the conversion as close to the source as possible.

Comment: Sorry, shopping questions are off-topic in this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into a lot of fancy analog conditioning, I think that the solution I'm proposing should work for you.  But you are going to have to add one more wire to your cable.

You have two problems,

1) The voltage drop in the power conductors is too high and the final voltage at your device is then too low for proper operation.

2) The voltage drop in the Sensor Ground wire is going to add an offset to your analog signals.  This degrades your accuracy - introducing possibly significant error to your measurements.

My approach would be to install a 5V linear regulator at your device.  You now feed perhaps +12V down the power wire and it is dropped to your desired voltage right at your sensor.

The power supply that feeds that regulator is floating.  That is: it does NOT share a ground with your system until it connects to the sensor - right at the sensor.  This is the extra wire that I mentioned above.

You now have 5 free wires coming from the sensor: the signal ground wire plus 4 analog signals.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flT42H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've shown a generic voltage regulator block.  You'll need to add the appropriate bypass capacitors as well as choose the most suitable part - the 7805 may not be the best part for your purposes.

There will be a voltage potential difference between your signal ground wire and the negative lead of your power supply.  This voltage difference is why it is important that this power supply ground be connected only at your sensor.

Because there isn't any current flowing on the Signal Ground wire, your analog signals are presented to your measuring device with the maximum precision.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few options.  First you could use power wires (+5 and Gnd) with a larger diameter, this will reduce the resistance and thus the voltage drop.  The other option would involve another wire.  You often see power supplies with a remote sense connection.  This is used to compensate for the voltage drop along the wire.  (search for remote sense power supply)